# adding horizontal gradient next to a text

Tags: css, gradient

I have a p tag with a text in it, which I want to add two horizontal line on each side of the text with a gradient affect. 
My issue is that I dont know how to get the lines on each side of the text.
Do I need to use a span? 
[image: Here is what I would like to look like. I have done gradient affect at the bottom of it, but I cant do it on each side]

```css
.blkbar {
    background: url("graphics/bkgd.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 60px;
}
.blkbar p {
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}
.blkbar_hl {
    height: 1px;
    background: #d4c293;
}
```

```html
<div class="col_full blkbar">
    <span class="blkbar_hl"></span> 
    <p>Call 374 60 275-737 Now To Reserve A Luxury Suite.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: considering the hassle and the size of the lines in question this would probably be one of the few times i'd use an image.

Comment: I have closed it as a dupe since this is a near enough duplicate of the linked question. You could modify the accepted answer to use gradients (or) you could have a look at the **Line with Gradient** sample in my answer. If you are unable to put them to use and get stuck somewhere, please update the question with more details, leave me a comment and I will reopen it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic approach for this purpose, is:

```css
h4:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 3px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #000 0%, transparent 100%);
}
h4:after {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 3px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000 0%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<h4>hello world</h4>
```

Comment: You should use `vertical-align:middle` to vertically center those pseudo elements.